# npm - 404 on package but URL returns 200

Tags: npm, babeljs

I'm trying to install deps for [ethAlarm](https://github.com/decentraland/ethalarm) and I'm getting a 404 on a package that seems to exist. The npm error logs are pasted below. When I hit the package's URL in my browser it returns a 200 response (for example: `https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2ftraverse`) but npm logs show that npm is getting a 404(?) I've had a similar problem with another project so I'm guessing it has to do with my config rather that babel per se... thanks in advance!

npm logs:

```
405 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2ftraverse 344ms
406 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @babel/traverse@7.0.0-beta.31 
404 Not Found: @babel/traverse@7.0.0-beta.31
407 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcode-frame 374ms
408 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @babel/code-frame@7.0.0-beta.31 404 Not Found: @babel/code-frame@7.0.0-beta.31
409 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2ftypes 393ms
410 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @babel/types@7.0.0-beta.31 404 Not Found: @babel/types@7.0.0-beta.31
411 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: @babel/traverse@7.0.0-beta.31
413 verbose Darwin 17.2.0
414 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
415 verbose node v8.3.0
416 verbose npm  v5.3.0
417 error code E404
418 error 404 Not Found: @babel/traverse@7.0.0-beta.31
419 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

.npmrc

```
prefix=/Users/example/npm
email=example@gmail.com
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
register=registry.npmjs.org
```